# get java Timezone id from +0000 format

Tags: java

I'm only getting this string "+0800" for a timezone from ihealth api. How can I get the corresponding java timezone id (like "US/Central") from this.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("Z");

try {
  Date date = sdf.parse("+0800");
  cal.setTime(date);
  System.out.println(cal.getTimeZone().getID());
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("error" + e.getMessage());
}
```

but this always prints "Etc/UTC" which is not "+0800". what am I missing here?

Comment: My guess (haven't tried it) would be that the Calendar object is created with a default timezone and that just changing the time doesn't change its timezone too. But what do you expect from this? Timezones usually span multiple countries, -0600 could be US/something, CA/something, MX/something ... you'll never really know.

Comment: A `Date` object does not have any timezone information.  The timezone you are parsing is merely used to compute the Date value, after which it is discarded.  Have a look at the methods of the [TimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) class, or if you're using Java 8 or later, [ZoneId](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html).

Answer (score 5):

The difficulty in what you are asking is that there are (almost?) always many timezone names associated with a given offset. So, for an offset of "+0800" we can do

```java
int rawOffset = 8 * 3600000;  // +0800 hours converted to milliseconds
String[] tzIds = java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(rawOffset);
for (String id : tzIds) {
    System.out.println(id);
}
```

and see the list

```
Antarctica/Casey
Asia/Brunei
Asia/Choibalsan
Asia/Chongqing
Asia/Chungking
Asia/Harbin
Asia/Hong_Kong
Asia/Kashgar
Asia/Krasnoyarsk
Asia/Kuala_Lumpur
Asia/Kuching
Asia/Macao
Asia/Macau
Asia/Makassar
Asia/Manila
Asia/Shanghai
Asia/Singapore
Asia/Taipei
Asia/Ujung_Pandang
Asia/Ulaanbaatar
Asia/Ulan_Bator
Asia/Urumqi
Australia/Perth
Australia/West
CTT
Etc/GMT-8
Hongkong
PRC
Singapore
```

If you want "***the*** corresponding java timezone id" (emphasis mine) then I guess you'll have to pick one. ;)

Comment: consider this case, For Indian Stantart time(IST) I'm getting "+0550". why 50 while IST is 5 hours and 30 mins ahead of GMT. How do I convert "+0550" (let's say I've date and time in some format) to GMT or any other time zone. or How do I convert "+0550" to "+05:30"

Comment: Actually what I want is, I get a time in unix time stamp format and timezone in "+0000". Now how do I convert this to GMT?

Answer (score 0):

Provided you use Java 8 you can use [ZoneOffset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html)

For example

```
ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.of("+0200");
TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(zoneOffset));
```

Edit: ZoneOffset.of() accepts offsetId, which is different from the 4 digits representation, so this would not solve the problem.

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("Z");

    try {
        Date date = sdf.parse("-0600");
        cal.setTime(date);
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error" + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: That would just output `+0800` again.

Comment: Why should they try that? Why does this solve their problem?